# Does $_POST work with a global variable?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this:

**page1.php**

```
Number of students<input type="number" name="number">
```

**page2.php**

I get the data from the `<input>` using the `$_POST` method and assign it to a var `$a`.

```
<? $a = $_POST['number']; ?>
```

**page3.php**

I define a fucntion in order to calculate something using a global variable.

```
<? function Calculate(){
     global $a;
     include 'page2.php'
     echo (3+10)/$a;
   }?>
```

Now, it says **Warning:** Division by zero in C:/.../page3.php on line **4**

But if you define a var `$a = 3`, for example, in the **page2.php** and call it in **page3.php**

```
<? function Calculate(){
     global $a;
     include 'page2.php';
     echo (3+10)/$a;
   }?>
```

It works perfectly.

Assuming that `$_POST` method gather vars, why isn't working with a global allocation? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: If you're including page2 in page3, then how would you be retrieving the form? This is a very strange construction.

Comment: Using globals in the first place is your mistake. You should definitely read up on software development in general (or at least coding properly in PHP, just look at the docs at php.net!!).

Comment: @nietonfir I just need to use a variable from a .php into another and I can't find how. I've searched a lot and nothing, even in php.net.

Comment: Oh please, you obviously didn't. You blindly copied the [include/require example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) without understanding it. [The answer from @lallu-anthoor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23415664/838733) should get you going though (but is missing essential parts, especially concerning input validation).

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$a` will be set only when a `POST` request is made to `page2.php`. But then, you won't be able to call your function as it is in `page3.php`.

If you go directly to `page3.php`, then there is no `POST` request and the value of `$a` will be 0. Thus the Division by Zero error.

If you want, you can include the `page3.php` in your `page2.php` and call your function from there when the `POST` request is made. But when doing this, you won't be needing that declaration of `$a` in the function. Instead you can pass it as an argument to the function.

```
function calculate($a=1) {
    /* Your code */
}
```

The `$a=1` in the function header is used to supply default value when nothing is passed when the function is called.

So your `page2.php` will look like

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['number'];
    include 'page3.php';
    Calculate($a);
?>
```

and your `page3.php` will look like

```
<?php
    function Calculate($a=1) {
        echo (3+10)/$a;
    }
?>
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not at the global variables, I doubt if you should use them in this case.

It's because of the `$_POST['number'];` your code fails.
When you include a page, the data of POST-request you did before (by submitting the form) does not exist anymore, resulting in no value being assigned to `$a`
However, when you're hard-coding `$a = 3`, the code will work because it's not depending on any kind of submitted data.

I would suggest you to go from page1 directly to page3 and retrieve the form values there, because I'm not getting the point of adding an extra page in-between.